# Issue when doing POST command to One To Many Relationship Tables

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have a one to many relationship between two java entities, lets say `Student` and `Grade`.

I am doing POST command to these two tables here is my basic set up:

Grade entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Student student;
```

---

Student entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
private Set<Grade> grades= new HashSet<>();
```

When I am doing GET to receive json data for a exisiting student(without grades), I receive json data like this:

```
{
    "grades":[],
    "studentId": 3,
    "studentName": "whatever"
}
```

And if I want to POST to student entity to add a new student, I could send json data like this:

```
{
    "grades":[],
    "studentName": "anything"
}
```

Here the json data does not contain "studentId" because I used `@GeneratedValue` annotation on the `studentId` variable.

So in order to allow myself doing POST to the `grade` entity, I had to add  `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` annotation, as follows:

Grade entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
private Student student;
```

---

Student entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Grade> grades= new HashSet<>();
```

What's interesting is, after I add `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`, I am able to do `GET`,`POST` to the `Grade` entity, and I am able to do `GET` to the `Student` entity, however the `POST` command to `Student` entity broke, no longer working.

Error I am getting:

> ```
> Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type
> Content-Language: null
> Content-Length: 360
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
> Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 20:09:44 GMT
> Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
> ```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Are you using spring mvc as your REST framework?

Comment: @Pace Yes, Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA